# Application to Use an Universal Camera Keyboard

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard

I'm trying to use an universal camera keyboard for our application. I followed installation guide and ubuntu is now able to see the device. All i need is a sample software to test the device.

To see what kind of keyboard i'm using, you can check out [its online guide](http://www.videotec.com/dep/DCZ_1051.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device manual has a typo. Where it says `7.5.5  Functional testing with Windows environment` it should say `Linux` instead of `Windows`.

I think you could test the device according to the manual:

```
Launch the application on the terminal and request
the /dev/ttyACM0 device.
Type in [Buzzer+] to activate the buzzer, type
[Buzzer-] to deactivate it. If the buzzer enables
and disables the keyboard it has been recognized
and is operating correctly.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply :)
i cannot get into dev directory by cd command. How can i call /dev/ttyACM0 ?

Comment: Hi again, i'm now able to get in dev folder. but i still cannot run the ttyACM0.

Comment: I think you need to launch the device application, on the terminal, and from that application request the ``/dev/ttyACM0`` device.

Comment: Hi, the thing is we haven't developed device application yet :)

If you know any open source alternative can you suggest a good one for me?

Comment: Sorry, i only downloaded the manual and took a look.