# How to open pseudo-terminal devices on terminal?

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to make functional test on a keyboard which is designed for security cameras' management and according to guide document, i need to launch the application on the terminal and request the dev/ttyACM0 device.

I don't have any application for this and i also haven't come across anyone who has something similar like that. ([Application to Use an Universal Camera Keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248596/application-to-use-an-universal-camera-keyboard))

What i wonder is, is there any way to test functionalities of my keyboard without installing any program?

I'm able to test my camera's stream over browser, is it possible to do something similar like that? If it is not, can you recommend any program to use in my ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/ttyACM0` sounds like a serial device. You can use a terminal emulator program to speak to a serial device.

For example, the screen program has this functionality built in. You can connect to a serial device at 115200 bps using the command `screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200`. You manual should tell you the speed you need to use on your device; 9600 bps is another common speed. You may need to install screen first using the command `sudo apt-get install screen`. To close screen when you're done, press <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>, release, and then press <kbd>k</kbd>.

Presumably you would then press buttons on your keyboard and see data appear in the terminal emulator window.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply :) i installed screen and minicom was already installed on my pc. but when i tried to onnect to a serial device at 115200 bps using the command screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200 or 9600 bps , it only shows blank screen on yakuake. :S

Comment: Hi again, screen was blank because it was waiting for me to try keyboard :D

Your suggestion solved my problem perfectly. Thank you very much for your help :)